# Inserting Record Type

Tags: oracle, types, insert, record

I have a source table, and a history table.  They are identical, except the history table has a `notes` column as the last column.

The table is large, 55 columns, which I do not want to list all the columns.  We do not want to use a trigger on this, but just create the history entry in the code itself.

If I simply do an `INSERT INTO <history> SELECT * FROM <source> WHERE......` I will get "not enough values".

I'm hoping to do something of this nature:  (Note this is just an anonymous block)

```
DECLARE
v_old_rec       company_table%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_old_rec
  FROM company_table
  WHERE company_id = 32789;

  INSERT INTO company_table_hist
  VALUES v_old_rec || ',MONTHLY UPDATE';
END;
```

Anything like this possible, so I do not have to list 55 columns?

Thank you.

Comment: If history table is the same as source table and the `notes` column's last you can use `insert into history as select source.*, null from source`

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov - as easy as it is, you gave a complete and correct answer. Please copy it to an Answer so the OP can mark it as correct answer and we can all move on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually:

```
INSERT INTO company_table_hist 
  (SELECT t.*, MONTHLY_UPD
  FROM company_table t
  WHERE company_id = 32789);
```

Of course `monthly_upd` must be bound somehow